What is this assassin movie?
So, I hate identify-this-X questions. A lot. And now I have one of my own.
I know there was an young male assassin and an older woman. She was his girlfriend, I think. Sort of May-December. There was a sex scene between the two, with frontal nudity of the older woman. I remember at the time thinking first that "wow, for a grandma she's not bad" and then "I can't believe she made this kind of movie." I can't for the life of me place the actress, but I remember that seeing her in this role was a shock.
They killed someone, or didn't kill someone and hid that person. The contractor comes after them in the end and they manage to kill everyone else involved. The final scene I remember showed a child "finger-shooting" a car behind (although I don't remember if the child was 'shooting' the protagonist or not.
Ah, yes Walt, thanks for that douse of cold water....
It was english-language, an American film, I believe. I saw it in the aught's, so I would guess made in early aughts, or late 90's.
Go ahead and down vote :) I can't remember anything else, and if I was you, I'd down-vote this. 

Hate it all you want, you still need to provide stuff like language\country & approximate decade. ;) I have a possible match, though.

@Walt Updated with info I knew I should have.

"Go ahead and down vote :) I can't remember anything else, and if I was you, I'd down-vote this." - Well, no need for that much self-deprecation, there are far worse ID questions than this one. (And I also asked some already, afterall they're on-topic, for better or worse.)

Possibly Shadowboxer from 2005. From Wiki:

Mikey (Cuba Gooding Jr.) and his stepmother/girlfriend, Rose (Helen Mirren) are contract killers. The two continue with their line of work despite the fact that Rose is suffering from cancer.
Mafia kingpin, Clayton, (Stephen Dorff) suspects that his pregnant wife Vicki (Vanessa Ferlito) may have been unfaithful, so he hires Mikey and Rose to kill her. [...] But as Rose enters Vicki's bedroom, Vicki's water breaks and she goes into labor. Taking pity on Vicki, Rose uses her prior medical training to deliver Vicki's baby, a boy she later names Anthony. Afterward, Mikey and Rose drive Vicki and her infant son to a local motel.

Clayton finds out about this years later and comes after Mikey, but Mikey manages to get the upper hand eventually. There are (several IIRC) sex scenes between Mirren and Gooding Jr., and though I don't quite remember the finger-gun thing,

Clayton is shot and killed in the end by Anthony, the boy they saved.

Here's the trailer:




Maybe, although I can't imagine Dame Helen in a sex scene. I'll watch it as soon as I can.

Actually, Mirren had some pretty risque scenes in quite a few movies. She wasn't always the Queen. ;)

OK, I found the scene and this is it. TYVM Walt.

Mirren was in Caligula, which was practically a soft porn movie.  And she was pretty hot in it too.
